# How do I parse a field in Crystal Reports that uses a record separator

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Crystal Reports XI, SQL Server 2008. I have a `varchar` column that uses a record separator to divide items but it disappears when it's rendered in Crystal Reports.

When I check the results in an editor I see that it's recognized as either RS or in Hex 1E. I would like to convert the RS to a comma if possible but anything that breaks it up would work.

Example Item oneRSItem TwoRSItem Three becomes Item OneItem TwoItem Three. I would like to have Item One, Item Two, Item Three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing which solved my issue.  I determined that the record separator was CHAR(30) [(using this table)](http://awesomesql.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/ascii-character-set-table/) and used that function in `REPLACE(table.Value, CHAR(30), ', ')` and it worked.